Prove That $\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z} dz = \ln(5) + 2\pi i$
Let $\gamma : [0, 2\pi] → \mathbb{C}$ be given by:
$$
\gamma(t)=\begin{cases}
    \ e^{it} &   0\leq t \leq \pi,\\
    2+3e^{it} & \pi \leq t \leq 2\pi.
\end{cases}
$$
Prove That $\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z} dz = \ln(5) + 2\pi i$.
Actually, I obtained $\ln(5)$ instead of $\ln(5) + 2\pi i$, because a branch could be $[-\pi /2, 3\pi/2]$ so $\ln(-1) = i\pi$ and the negative of this value will cancel out the integral which pertains to $0\leq t \leq \pi$.
My Calculations: $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}dz = 
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{ie^{it}}{e^{it}} dt + 
\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \frac{3ie^{it}}{2+3e^{it}} dt =
i\pi + \ln(5) - \ln(-1) = i\pi + \ln(5) - i\pi.
$$
Thank you for your time.

You should share your calculations instead of just telling us what did you obtained.

I just shared my calculations.

You could note that by closing the curve appropriately that you could reduce the problem to the real integral from $1 \to 5$.

Is $f(t)$ same as $\gamma$?

Presumably $f=\gamma$?

$f$ is a parameterization of the curve.

@copper.hat: You mean that the correct answer is $ln(5)$? if not could you explain more?

You can't choose the branch $[-\pi /2, 3\pi/2]$. The second half of the curve pass through the line of discontinuity.

Extend the curve to include the path joining $5$ to $1$. Then $\int_\gamma {1 \over z}dz + \int_5^1 {1 \over z} dz= 2 \pi i$ (residue of ${1 \over z}$ at $z=0$) from which the result follows.

but $z=0$ is not in the interior of the extended curve.

@schneiderlog Might want to check that again.

$0$ is in the interior of the extended curve. If $0$ weren't in the interior of the (closed) extended curve, the integral would be $0$ by Cauchy's Theorem.

Based on parameterization, the extended curve would be as follows:  starting from $1$ and go to $-1$ on positive unit semicircle counterclockwise then travel to $5$ from $-1$ on positive semicircle of radius $3$ and center at $2$ clockwise, finally move to $1$ on the straight line. Why $z=0$ is in the interior?

@schneiderlog That is not correct. The path is continuous.

It doesn't travel from $5$ to $-1$. It travels from $-1$ to $5$ on the lower semicircle of radius $3$ and center $2$ counterclockwise.

Is is easier to use the residue theorem and avoid $\log$ corner cases.
If you must use $\log$, you need to be careful around $-1$ (I am using the principle branch of the $\log$).
We have
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{\gamma}{1 \over z} dz &=& \int_0^{\pi-\epsilon} {\gamma'(t) \over \gamma(t)}dt+ \int_{\pi-\epsilon}^{\pi+\epsilon} {\gamma'(t) \over \gamma(t)}dt + \int_{\pi-\epsilon}^{2 \pi} {\gamma'(t) \over \gamma(t)}dt \\
&=& \log \gamma(\pi-\epsilon) - \log \gamma(0)+ \int_{\pi-\epsilon}^{\pi+\epsilon} {\gamma'(t) \over \gamma(t)}dt + \log \gamma(2 \pi)- \log \gamma(\pi+\epsilon)
\end{eqnarray}
Note that we can bound (for $\epsilon$ suitably small) $|\int_{\pi-\epsilon}^{\pi+\epsilon} {\gamma'(t) \over \gamma(t)}dt| \le 3\cdot 2 \epsilon$, and so $\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \int_{\pi-\epsilon}^{\pi+\epsilon} {\gamma'(t) \over \gamma(t)}dt = 0$. Finally, a straightforward computation shows that $\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \log \gamma(\pi-\epsilon) = i\pi$ and $\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \log \gamma(\pi+\epsilon) = -i \pi$, hence we end up with
$\int_\gamma {1 \over z} dz = 2\pi i + \log \gamma(2\pi) = 2\pi i + \log 5$.

Let's just focus on the lower limit of the integral, where you need to evaluate $\ln(2+3e^{it})$ in the limit $t\to \pi$. Note that your $t$ is always greater than $\pi$. So I use $t=\pi+\varepsilon$.
$$\ln(2+3e^{i(\pi+\varepsilon)})=\ln(2+(-3)e^{i\varepsilon})=\ln(2-3\cos\varepsilon-3i\sin\varepsilon)$$
So if you try to plot it, this point, in the limit $\varepsilon\to 0$ approaches $(-1,0)$ from below the real axis. That means that the argument is $-\pi$. Therefore $$\ln(2+3e^{i(\pi+\varepsilon)})=-i\pi$$
